# add new row to textarea input while editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how to add new row/line to textarea while editing that is when the number of letters exceeds number of cols of the textarea add new line automatically.

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't. When do you stop adding new lines?  After 5? 10? When it takes up half the page?  I'd recommend you set a sensible width and height, and just allow the textarea to implement scrolling as users will expect it to do.
However if you're set on this and have a good reason, then it should be a fairly straightforward matter of keeping tabs on the number of characters via the textarea's keyup event or similar and changing the rows attribute when needed.

Comment: Also note that newer browsers (FF4, Chrome) allow for resizing the text areas by dragging the lower right corner.

Comment: aha but i don't want the user control the size of the textarea,in addition i don't want him to scroll just do his comment and feel everty thing is ok while he editing

Comment: if I was that user, I'd start to feel a little annoyed that I was being given so little space in which to work, but that's just me possibly - but then again I'd just resize the thing as Xion points out we can do these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basic code to achieve this, tested in this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/NZbZn/). It will need work, obviously, but shows the basic concept.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    //after typing occurs
    jQuery('textarea#expander').keyup(function(){

        //figure out how many chars
        var length = jQuery(this).val().length;

        //if more than 10
        if(length > 10){

            //if the modulus 10 of the length is zero, there are a multiple of 10 chars, so we need to extend by a row
            //(NOTE the obvious problem - this will expand while deleting chars too!)
            if((length % 10) == 0){

                //figure out the number of rows, increment by one, and reset rows attrib
                var rows = jQuery(this).attr('rows');
                rows++;

                jQuery(this).attr('rows', rows);    
            }  
        }   
    });    
});
```

Again though, consider the UI implications first.

Comment: thanks a lot :) i took the jquery plugin it helps a lot after modifications :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$('textarea').keyup(function (e) {
    var rows = $(this).val().split("\n");
    $(this).prop('rows', rows.length);
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! One-liner, plain JS version: `elt.addEventListener('keyup',() => elt.setAttribute('rows',elt.value.split('\n').length))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery AutoResize Plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/

Comment: aha thanx for that,but it depend on the animation that is on time,not on number of cols,anyway thanx alot :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
<textarea id="ta" onkeyup="checkScroll(this)" style="height:4em; overflow:auto">
asdf
</textarea>

<script>
function checkScroll(obj) { 
  if(obj.clientHeight < obj.scrollHeight) {
    obj.style.height = (parseInt(obj.style.height)+1) + 'em';
  }
}
</script>
```

And you could add a height limit in the "if" condition if you wanted.

(Didn't worry about making this unobtrusive -- just getting the point across.)

Answer (score 0):

try this

var txt = $("textarea#idhere");
txt.val( txt.val() + "\nSomething here\n\nAgain");

Answer (score 0):

Here's plain JS one liner that automatically sets the number of rows of the textarea to the number of lines that it contains:

```js
elt = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0]

elt.addEventListener('keyup',()=>elt.setAttribute('rows',elt.value.split('\n').length))
```

```html
<textarea rows='1'>Type some lines!</textarea>
```