# Styling empty textarea height

Tags: html, css, input, textarea

I am trying to put textarea in my layout. However, when it's empty with only placeholder, there seems to be an extra row added. I wish to get rid of it as it breaks my layout. I cannot set fixed height as the textarea is fluid depending on the text input.

Here's the screenshot.
[image]

Here are all rules as shown in Safari (I omitted those that are not active).

CSS:

```
min-height: 36px;
padding: 16px;
margin-right: 16px;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-size: 14px;
max-height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
resize: none;
width: 80%
-webkit-appearance: textarea;
background-color: white;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 1px;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: initial;
border-right-color: initial;
border-bottom-color: initial;
border-left-color: initial;
border-image-source: initial;
border-image-slice: initial;
border-image-width: initial;
border-image-outset: initial;
border-image-repeat: initial;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-user-select: text;
flex-direction: column;
cursor: auto;
white-space: pre-wrap;
word-wrap: break-word;
margin-top: 0em;
margin-bottom: 0em;
margin-left: 0em;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 400;
font-family: -apple-system;
font-variant: normal;
color: initial;
letter-spacing: normal;
word-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal;
text-transform: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-shadow: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: start;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
list-style: none;
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: Here's the same element without min-height and padding applied.
[image]

Comment: This is cause of the 16px padding that you have to the textarea. Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0h7wcg0/) for the same

Comment: Hey @SatejS! Check my updated post please, removing padding and min-height didn't fix it!

Comment: @SatejS Margin is already set to 0 as you can see and I cannot set padding to 0 as it's a part of style. Even if I do, the blue part doesn't change as it is not affected by padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers set the default rows of a textarea to 2 rows as you can see here: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/textarea.

There is no css property to modify the number of rows in a textarea.

What you could do if you really need 1 row is set rows='1' and then use javascript to dynamically add more rows as the user types. You can find an example of that here: [add new row to textarea input while editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6197784/add-new-row-to-textarea-input-while-editing)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Dumb me was trying to put col="1" instead of rows! I actually had the JavaScript in place already, so thanks for thinking through the problem in more detail!

Answer (score 1):

The height of a row in textarea is set by line-height.

For example:

```
<textarea rows="1">Text text</textarea>
```

If you set the following:

```
textarea { font-size: 16px; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 1; }
```

By inspecting the textarea element you'll find out that it has a height of 16px.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! Unfortunately I can accept only 1 answer :( And user1046457 just provided an answer that suited even better for my specific problem.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.