# How to set textarea height using min-height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I am trying to create a message input field, using textarea. The reason I am using textarea is to be able to dynamically change the height.

To be able to dynamically change the height of the textarea and the parent divs, I have implemented this code.

The code works, just fine. To be able to use this JavaScript code I have to use **min-height** on the textarea.  The problem is that I want to set the height of the textarea to **10px** but it simply doesn't want to work, when using **min-height**. I does somehow work when I use **height**, but then the JavaScript won't work.

UPDATE:

I am just trying to create a field where the user can write a message and then post it.
Currently the textarea is too tall in my opinion, there is no reason for it to be taller than needed. So i want the height to initially be 20px, and then be able to expand as the user types.

**UPDATE UPDATE:**
I want to know how to set the height of the textarea to 10px or 20px, but still be able to dynamically change the height when the user types, using the javascript code i have provided

Any ideas on how to solve this? Btw, I'm not very well versed in CSS.

```js
var areaName = "finder__input";
var textarea = document.getElementById(areaName);

textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
  const textareaHeight = textarea.clientHeight;
  textarea.style.height = "auto";
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #292929;
  background-color: #616f91
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.finder {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  background-color: #f6f5f0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* width: 722px; */
  padding: 3px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px black, -1px -1px 1px white;
}

.finder__outer {
  position: relative;
  /* width: 700px; */
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 5px -2px black, inset -10px -10px 5px -7px white;
}

.finder__input {
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  background-color: red;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  min-height: 10px;
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="finder">
    <div class="finder__outer" id="finder__outer">
      <textarea id="finder__input" class="finder__input" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Write a message..."></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain in a paragraph or two what's that you're exactly building? And why would you ever want to set textarea to 10px?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i have made an update

Comment: Still the question is not clear

Comment: @SagarV I want to know how to set the height of the textarea to 10px or 20px, but still be able to dynamically change the height when the user types, using the javascript code i have provided

Comment: @NG set `rows="1"` for the textarea. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34876793/2427065

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Resize textarea height on input

This is basically similar to this jQuery related question: [Resize Textarea on Input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57953324/383904).
Here's a rewrite in *vanilla* JavaScript

```js
const textareaResize = (elTextarea) => {
  elTextarea.style.height = "auto";
  const h = elTextarea.scrollHeight;
  elTextarea.style.height = `${h}px`;
};

document.querySelectorAll(".flexheight").forEach((elTextarea) => {
  elTextarea.addEventListener("input", textareaResize); // on input
  textareaResize(elTextarea); // on init
});
```

```css
textarea.flexheight {
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: inherit;
  height: 1rem;
}
```

```html
Starts small and increment height as user types: <br>
<textarea class="flexheight" placeholder="Write a message..."></textarea>
<br>
<textarea class="flexheight" placeholder="Write about yourself..."></textarea>
```

Comment: I cant get this code to work. However the code you initially provided worked fine. But do you happen to know hoe to make the textarea shorter in height?

Comment: @NG Should work the same if instead of `document.querySelectorAll(".flexheight")` (which was for demo purpose!) you use the appropriate selector: `document.querySelectorAll(".finder__input")`. To make your textarea initially shorter 
 - play with the CSS `height`.

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but I am certain that it still doesnt work. The textarea doesn’t expand

Comment: Here you go, the code before the modification. 
There's really not much of a change besides the selectors, and that this one works for one element only: https://jsfiddle.net/RokoCB/rw4o5y3e/

Answer (score 0):

```
var areaName = "finder__input";
var textarea = document.getElementById(areaName);

textarea.addEventListener("input", function() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
  const textareaHeight = textarea.clientHeight;
  //textarea.style.height = "10px";
  textarea.style.minHeight = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
});
```

try using `minHeight`

Comment: This unfortunately does not seem to work. When doing this, the textarea expand on every character input, rather than on line shift